# How to format an EDIFACT composite with conditional data elements

Tags: parsing, edifact

I am currently working on a small project to generate EDIFACT messages and I want to know how the example composite below should be generated as a string if `0004 = ATEPA` and `0008 = ADDR01`?

Should conditional elements that are empty be excluded from the output string?  If so, what would be the output string look like if `0007` was blank?.

Would it look like `ATEPA::ADDR01`, or would it be `ATEPA:ADDR01`?  I am hoping it's not the latter as parsing it would be impossible as there would be no way to determine if `ADDR01` belongs to `0007` or `0008`.

```
!======!===================================!===!========!
! S002 ! INTERCHANGE SENDER                ! M !        !
! 0004 ! Sender identification             ! M ! an..35 !
! 0007 ! Identification code qualifier     ! C ! an..4  !
! 0008 ! Address for reverse routing       ! C ! an..14 ! 
!======!===================================!===!========!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be **ATEPA::ADDR01** because the composite element makes up the whole element, so the placeholder for the second composite remains intact.

Comment: Okay, what about if I removed `ADDR01` would that make it `ATEPA::` or just `ATEPA`?

Comment: It should be just ATEPA in that scenario.  Do yourself a huge favor and download this product: http://liaison.com/products/integrate/edi-notepad.  It is free and it will help you with EDI syntax.

Comment: I tried downloading that the other day, but it will only accept a work email address and not personal email addresses.

Comment: You might go on a mailing list, but I don't think anyone will contact you.  I'm sure they blocked hotmail, gmail, etc, but you could probably make up a domain as well and it would work.  For a free utility that is that high quality for EDI documents, it's worth the sales call.